# what causes 'deadlock; recursive locking' error in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deadlock

My rails app tracks any delayed_job errors, and we saw this one today for the first time:

```
deadlock; recursive locking /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.r
```

The app has been performing flawlessly, with millions of delayed jobs handled w/o error.

Is this just "one of those random things" or is there something different we can/should do to prevent it from happening again?

I'm especially confused because we run only a single worker.

Our setup: Rails 3.2.12, Heroku app, Postgres, several web dynos but only 1 worker dyno.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm facing a similar situation

Comment: I never found an answer, if I do I will post it here and hope you will do likewise.

Comment: I think a new gem caiused the problem. And our AWS architecture was not mapped properly. But we haven't been able to resolve it fully

Comment: Are you using Unicorn as server? I think it has problems with Rails 3 not being thread safe. I'm having the same problem in my unicorn apps but not in my Thin apps. Could I be right?

Comment: At the time I was using Thin. Been using unicorn for several months. Haven't seen it before or since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with Rack.  See similar bug reports:

1. https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/658
2. https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/349

Comment: We haven't see it since, but it does appear to be an issue for rails 3.2 apps with rack 1.4.5 so that first link refers to a patch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The fix was to upgrade rubygems. The way I used to upgrade:

`gem update --system`

Ref: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/2137#issuecomment-720775183